# how to configure the force parameters in force directed graph so that the graph is stable

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I'm trying to make a force directed graph using d3.js but as the number of nodes increases the graph becomes highly unstable and it starts vibrating, also it goes beyond the canvas limits.
What I'm trying to acheive is all the dependent Nodes below the centre node and dependencies above it so it is visually understandable

```
var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    node,
    link;



var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {return d.id;}).distance(400).strength(0))
    .force("collison",d3.forceCollide(200).strength(0.5).iterations(50))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width/2 , height/2))
    .on("tick", ticked);





var graphDiv = document.getElementById("graph_view");


update(temp2.links,temp2.nodes);

function update(links, nodes) {


    svg.append('defs').append('marker')
    .attrs({'id':'arrowhead',
        'viewBox':'-0 -5 10 15',
        'refX':10,
        'refY':0,
        'orient':'auto',
        'markerWidth':15,
        'markerHeight':15,
        'xoverflow':'visible'})
    .append('polygon')
    .attr('points', '0,-5  10 ,0  0,5')
    .attr('fill', 'black')
    .style('stroke','none');

    var w = graphDiv.clientWidth;
    var h = graphDiv.clientHeight;
    svg
        .attr("width",2000)
        .attr("height",2000);


    node = svg.selectAll()
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .on("click",click)
        .on("contextmenu",onRightClick)
        .on("mouseover", node_hover)
        .call(d3.drag()                  // draggable function 
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged) 
                //.on("end", dragended)
        );
    console.log("creating graph")
    node.append("rect")
        .attr("x",-150)
        .attr("width", 300)
        .attr("height",75)
        .attr("rx",10)
        .style("fill", "white")
        .style("stroke","black")

    node.append("title")
        .text(function (d) {return d.id;});

    node.append("text")
        .attr("font-size",10)
        .attr("align", "centre")
        .attr("font-family","Arial")
        .text(function (d) {console.log(d); return d.id;})
        .attr("text-anchor","middle")
        .attr("alignment-baseline","central")
        .attr("y", 37.5)
        .attr("x", 0)


    // console.log("------LINKS DATA---------");
    console.log(links);
    link = svg.selectAll()
        .data(links)
        .enter().append("path") 
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr('marker-end','url(#arrowhead)')

    link.append("title")
        .text(function (d) {return d.type;});



    simulation
        .nodes(nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked);

    simulation.force("link")
        .links(links);
}

function ticked() {

    link.attr("d", function(d) {
            var x1 = d.source.x,
                y1 = d.source.y,
                x2 = d.target.x,
                y2 = d.target.y,
                dx = x2 - x1,
                dy = y2 - y1,
                dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy),
                drx = dr,
                dry = dr,
                xRotation = 0, // degrees
                largeArc = 0, // 1 or 0
                sweep = 1; // 1 or 0

                // Self edge.
                if ( x1 === x2 && y1 === y2 ) {
                  // Fiddle with this angle to get loop oriented.
                  xRotation = 0;

                  // Needs to be 1.
                  largeArc = 1;

                  drx = 30;
                  dry = 50;
                  x2 = x2 + 10;
                  y2 = y2 + 1;

                  return "M" + x1 + ","+y1 +"A" +drx +","+dry+" "+xRotation +","+ largeArc+ "," + sweep +" "+ x2+","+y2;
                } 
                return "M" + x1 + "," + y1 + "L" +" " + x2 + "," + y2;

          });

    // link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    // .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    // .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    // .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(1000, Math.min(width - 1000, d.x)); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(100*d.level+1000, Math.min(100*d.level-1000, d.y)); });



}
//Hover function
function node_hover(d)
{
    console.log("on hover");
    console.log(d.id);
    var tip = document.getElementById("node tooltip");
    // console.log(tip);
    tip.innerText = "edit node " + d.id;
    tip.style.visibility ="visible";


}
//new pop up window on Single click
function onRightClick(d){
    console.log("RIght click");
    if(d3.event.defaultPrevented) return;
    console.log(d.id);
    var content = document.getElementById("modal-content-data");
    content.innerText = "This is node " +d.id;
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    modal.style.display = "block";

    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    if(force){
        console.log("Stopping force");
        force.stop();
    }
}
//Expand new node on Double Click
function click(d){
    if(d3.event.defaultPrevented) return;
    console.log(d);
    var t = graph_generator(d.id,1);
    console.log("dynamic node ")
    console.log(t);

    d3.selectAll("path").remove();
    d3.selectAll("g").remove();    
    update(t.links,t.nodes);


}

function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart()
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
}
```